# c# asmx web service. How to read in post data from aspx page

Tags: c#, web-services

I am writing a web service for my company using c#. So I have a test page default.aspx.
From the aspx page I have an input name="zip" which i need to pass to the webservice. 
I can't figure out how to get the posted data. Webservice will run an sql statement based on the zip code passed as xml. then returns the zipcode xml as a response.

code from aspx page below.

```
string sendXml = String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>,
                            <zip>{0}</zip>",
                                Request["zip"]);
                string postXml = "xmlRequest=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sendXml);
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:51857/zipfinder.asmx/showRecords");
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentLength = postXml.Length;
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(postXml);
                    writer.Close();
                }

                var result = "";
                try
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string getResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Response.Write(getResult);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("error: " + ex.ToString());
                }
```

then on the .asmx page

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public DataSet getZip() {            
            DataSet dataSet = db.QueryDataRows("*", "zip_codes_simple", "zip = '00501' or zip = '00544'", "", "zip_codes_simple");
            return dataSet;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public XmlDocument showRecords(){
            DataSet dataSet = getZip();
            string recs = "";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
            doc.AppendChild(dec);
            XmlNode root = doc.CreateElement("zipcodes");
            doc.AppendChild(root);
            XmlElement zip = doc.CreateElement("zip");
            XmlElement type = doc.CreateElement("type");
            XmlElement primaryCity = doc.CreateElement("primaryCity");
            XmlElement state = doc.CreateElement("state");
            XmlElement latitude = doc.CreateElement("latitude");
            XmlElement longitude = doc.CreateElement("longitude");

            foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        zip.InnerText = dr["zip"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(zip);
                        type.InnerText = dr["type"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(type);
                        primaryCity.InnerText = dr["primary_city"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(primaryCity);
                        state.InnerText = dr["state"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(state);
                        latitude.InnerText = dr["latitude"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(latitude);
                        longitude.InnerText = dr["longitude"].ToString();
                        root.AppendChild(longitude);
                        //recs = "<p>" + dr["zip"] + ", " + dr["primary_city"] + "</p>";
                        //Response.Write("<p>" + dr["zip"] + " in " + dr["state"]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //recs = "<p style='color: red;'>Invalid user name or password</p>";
                }
            }

            return doc;
        }
```

How can i get the zip code from the aspx page to pass to the query where zip = ''
I am looking for something to read in the formatted string and extract the zip code from the incoming xml document.

any help appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you want to get the value from the `<input type='text' name='zip' />` in your page. Since it is not an `asp:TextBox`, you should get it using [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), so your code would look like this:

```
string sendXml = String.Format(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>,
                            <zip>{0}</zip>",
                                Request.Form["zip"]);
```

But there is another solution: Instead of doing this:

```
<input type='text' name='zip' />
```

You could use an ASP.NET Webform control:

```
<asp:TextBox runat='server' ID='zip' />
```

And then you could get the value with `zip.Text`.

Is there any reason why you're not doing this?

Comment: Yes, its because we have a cms that doesn't support inline server tags. Is there a way in the asmx file taht i can call the xml zip code. Example in the aspx i can use Request["field"], however, I have not yet seen a way to reference the xml coming in. Basically i need something to read that xml, read the one field and use the value in the sql statement.

Comment: Ok, so `Request["zip"]` is working? If not, try `Request.Form["zip"]`. To extract an information from a XML document, you can use xPath, eg `/zipcodes/zip` will match all `zip`s inside `zipcode`. As the variable `string getResult = reader.ReadToEnd();` contains the response XML, you could load it into a XmlDocument and then do de query by using `doc.SelectNodes("/xpath/to/node")`. I'm not sure if I understood your problem.